# How to change the placeholder font on a jQuery Mobile page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

On a jQuery Mobile page, I have the following:

```
<input name="SearchCriteria" id="SearchCriteria" value="" 
       placeholder="Case Number, Caption, Client, Firm or Claimaint." />
```

I am trying to reduce the placeholder font a bit..  I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css) answer, but it doesn't seem to do anything on a jQuery Mobile page.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Is your mobile browser supported for placeholder? Here's a list of supported browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

Comment: Which JQM version are you using?

Comment: @Omar I am using 1.3.2

Comment: @mk117 I am testing it in Firefox 31.  My target browsers are iOS 7 Safari, whatever is the latest Chrome in Android as of now.  The placeholders show up... but I want them a different size.  So it is supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, but if you are testing it on a mobile, try different browsers too. Because some mobile browsers are very limited. Always try first how it will look on the original browser that came with the phone.

```
/* all */
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#f00; }
::-moz-placeholder { color:#f00; } /* firefox 19+ */
:-ms-input-placeholder { color:#f00; } /* ie */
input:-moz-placeholder { color:#f00; }

/* individual: webkit */
#field2::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#00f; }
#field3::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#090; background:lightgreen; text-transform:uppercase; }
#field4::-webkit-input-placeholder { font-style:italic; text-decoration:overline; letter-spacing:3px; color:#999; }

/* individual: mozilla */
#field2::-moz-placeholder { color:#00f; }
#field3::-moz-placeholder { color:#090; background:lightgreen; text-transform:uppercase; }
#field4::-moz-placeholder { font-style:italic; text-decoration:overline; letter-spacing:3px; color:#999; }
```

Comment: It works on Safari in iOS and Chrome, but not Firefox on the desktop for whatever reason.  Anyway, good enough - I am targeting mobile only.